# Interleaving the columns of two matrices horizontally in a particular way

Tags: matrix

I have two matrices:

```
Matrix1 = 
  Table[NumberForm[N[(10 i + 9 j)/70, 3], {4, 2}], {i, 33}, {j, 18}];

MatrixForm[Matrix1]

Matrix2 = 
  Table[NumberForm[N[(12 i + 17 j)/70, 3], {4, 2}], {i, 33}, {j, 13}];

MatrixForm[Matrix2]
```

I want to "interleave" the first column of Matrix 1 horizontally with all the columns of Matrix 2. Then the second column of Matrix 1 with all the columns of Matrix 2;  and continue like this until the last column of Matrix 1 has been interleaved with all the columns of Matrix 2. The following is my attempt to do this; here I have only gone as far as interleaving the first six columns of Matrix 1 with all the columns of Matrix 2; (I stopped at 6 for decorum sake...)

```
Table[{Matrix1[[i]][[1]], Matrix2[[i]][[1]], Matrix1[[i]][[1]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[2]], Matrix1[[i]][[1]], Matrix2[[i]][[3]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[1]], Matrix2[[i]][[4]], Matrix1[[i]][[1]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[5]], Matrix1[[i]][[1]], Matrix2[[i]][[6]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[1]], Matrix2[[i]][[7]], Matrix1[[i]][[1]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[8]], Matrix1[[i]][[1]], Matrix2[[i]][[9]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[1]], Matrix2[[i]][[10]], Matrix1[[i]][[1]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[11]], Matrix1[[i]][[1]], Matrix2[[i]][[12]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[1]], Matrix2[[i]][[13]], Matrix1[[i]][[2]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[1]], Matrix1[[i]][[2]], Matrix2[[i]][[2]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[2]], Matrix2[[i]][[3]], Matrix1[[i]][[2]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[4]], Matrix1[[i]][[2]], Matrix2[[i]][[5]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[2]], Matrix2[[i]][[6]], Matrix1[[i]][[2]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[7]], Matrix1[[i]][[2]], Matrix2[[i]][[8]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[2]], Matrix2[[i]][[9]], Matrix1[[i]][[2]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[10]], Matrix1[[i]][[2]], Matrix2[[i]][[11]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[2]], Matrix2[[i]][[12]], Matrix1[[i]][[2]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[13]], Matrix1[[i]][[3]], Matrix2[[i]][[1]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[3]], Matrix2[[i]][[2]], Matrix1[[i]][[3]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[3]], Matrix1[[i]][[3]], Matrix2[[i]][[4]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[3]], Matrix2[[i]][[5]], Matrix1[[i]][[3]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[6]], Matrix1[[i]][[3]], Matrix2[[i]][[7]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[3]], Matrix2[[i]][[8]], Matrix1[[i]][[3]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[9]], Matrix1[[i]][[3]], Matrix2[[i]][[10]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[3]], Matrix2[[i]][[11]], Matrix1[[i]][[3]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[12]], Matrix1[[i]][[3]], Matrix2[[i]][[13]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[4]], Matrix2[[i]][[1]], Matrix1[[i]][[4]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[2]], Matrix1[[i]][[4]], Matrix2[[i]][[3]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[4]], Matrix2[[i]][[4]], Matrix1[[i]][[4]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[5]], Matrix1[[i]][[4]], Matrix2[[i]][[6]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[4]], Matrix2[[i]][[7]], Matrix1[[i]][[4]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[8]], Matrix1[[i]][[4]], Matrix2[[i]][[9]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[4]], Matrix2[[i]][[10]], Matrix1[[i]][[4]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[11]], Matrix1[[i]][[4]], Matrix2[[i]][[12]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[4]], Matrix2[[i]][[13]], Matrix1[[i]][[5]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[1]], Matrix1[[i]][[5]], Matrix2[[i]][[2]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[5]], Matrix2[[i]][[3]], Matrix1[[i]][[5]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[4]], Matrix1[[i]][[5]], Matrix2[[i]][[5]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[5]], Matrix2[[i]][[6]], Matrix1[[i]][[5]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[7]], Matrix1[[i]][[5]], Matrix2[[i]][[8]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[5]], Matrix2[[i]][[9]], Matrix1[[i]][[5]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[10]], Matrix1[[i]][[5]], Matrix2[[i]][[11]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[5]], Matrix2[[i]][[12]], Matrix1[[i]][[5]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[13]], Matrix1[[i]][[6]], Matrix2[[i]][[1]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[6]], Matrix2[[i]][[2]], Matrix1[[i]][[6]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[3]], Matrix1[[i]][[6]], Matrix2[[i]][[4]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[6]], Matrix2[[i]][[5]], Matrix1[[i]][[6]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[6]], Matrix1[[i]][[6]], Matrix2[[i]][[7]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[6]], Matrix2[[i]][[8]], Matrix1[[i]][[6]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[9]], Matrix1[[i]][[6]], Matrix2[[i]][[10]], 
   Matrix1[[i]][[6]], Matrix2[[i]][[11]], Matrix1[[i]][[6]], 
   Matrix2[[i]][[12]], Matrix1[[i]][[6]], Matrix2[[i]][[13]]}, {i, 1, 
   33}] // MatrixForm
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `Transpose@Riffle[Transpose@Matrix1, Transpose@Matrix2]` ?

Comment: To George2079; your command riffles the two matrices but, it is not interleaving them in the manner that I described above.  Notice that the first column of Matrix 1 is interleaved with each column of Matrix 2.  Next the second column of Matrix 1 is interleaved with each column of Matrix 2;  etc. ; until the last column of Matrix 1 is interleaved with each column of Matrix 2.  Thank you for your attempt though!

Comment: can you make a smaller example so you can show the whole result? What are the dimensions of the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible approaches with `Riffle`:

```
dim1 = Last@Dimensions[Matrix1];
dim2 = Last@Dimensions[Matrix2];
tMatrix2 = Transpose[Matrix2];

Transpose[Join @@ 
   (Riffle[ConstantArray[Matrix1[[All, #]], dim2], tMatrix2] & /@ Range[dim1])
]
```

or

```
Transpose[
   Riffle[
      Join @@ (ConstantArray[#, Last@Dimensions[Matrix2]] & /@ Transpose[Matrix1]), 
      Transpose[Matrix2], 
      {2, -1, 2}]
]
```

An approach with `Outer`:

```
Transpose[Join @@ Outer[Sequence, Transpose[Matrix1], Transpose[Matrix2], 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you Xavier (and thank you George)! Indeed that last code does exactly what I need! Thanks!